# Angular explicitly exclude package

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, angular-universal, universal

I'm building a library, let's call It "@***/ngx-maps" which import "@types/leaflet" and importing it as shown below.

```
import { Content, Layer, Popup } from 'leaflet';
```

I'm loading the leaflet package from a CDN dynamically. I was expecting that the npm package "leaflet" would not be required during the build.

But Angular still tells me that:

> ERROR in The target entry-point "@***/ngx-maps" has missing dependencies: "leaflet"

How can I tell angular to not include it at build and that it is not needed?

Comment: Hi @GreG7512 and welcome to the community. Maybe if you give us more code, your `index.html`, `angular.json` and `package.json` or how you dynamically import `leaflet` we could help more !

Comment: Sorry I did not understood the interface, so I did revert the edit.